# Sensors Location in Date Pipe

Tags: typescript, date-pipe

I have a timestamp, 1674169200000. In french format, in GMT+1, I wish an hour set to 00:00:00.

When I use `this.datePipe.transform(1674169200000, 'mediumTime')` with a french location (in debug mode : Sensors -> no override, Timezone ID = Europe/Paris), I see 00:00:00.
But when I change my Sensors to Location Portugal (Timezone ID : Atlantic/Azores), I see 22:00:00.

I don't understand how my DatePipe can change the hour. In constructor, the locale is always 'fr'.

I want always see french hour (00:00:00), no matter from where is my client. I tried to change in "transform" the 3rd argument (timezone = 'Europe/Paris'), the 4th argument (locale = 'fr'), nothing change...